# How to limit tag_cloud to the top 20 taggings_count?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, acts-as-taggable-on, tag-cloud

How can we limit the `tag_cloud` to 20 of the tags with highest count?

```
[1] pry(main)> Tag.find(1)
  Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Tag:0x007fcae0cf88e0 id: 1, name: "test", taggings_count: 4>
[2] pry(main)> Tag.find(4)
  Tag Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
=> #<Tag:0x007fcae0ca0ac8 id: 4, name: "test the comma", taggings_count: 0>
[3] pry(main)>
Started GET "/as

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
```

**tag.rb**

```
scope :top_20, -> do
  limit(20) #This limits it to the 20 tags first made regardless of if those tags have since been deleted?
end
```

How can we remove tags from the `tag_cloud` with `taggings_count: 0` (this may necessitate another SO question)? Bonus points if you answer it here ;)

**_tags.html.erb**

```
<% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag), :class => css_class %>
<% end %>
```

Please let me know if you need further **explanation or code** to help you help me :-]

**schema**

```
  create_table "taggings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.integer  "taggable_id"
    t.string   "taggable_type"
    t.integer  "tagger_id"
    t.string   "tagger_type"
    t.string   "context",       limit: 128
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end

  add_index "taggings", ["tag_id", "taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context", "tagger_id", "tagger_type"], name: "taggings_idx", unique: true
  add_index "taggings", ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context"

  create_table "tags", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "taggings_count", default: 0
  end

  add_index "tags", ["name"], name: "index_tags_on_name", unique: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code :

```
scope :top_20, -> {
  where("taggings_count != 0").order("taggings_count DESC").limit(20)
}
```

Comment: You are quick! I did like the look of the tag_cloud as mixing and matching in sizes instead of all the highest ones showing first then going down in desc order. Would it be possible to maintain that cloud feel while only showing the top_20 in varying order within the top 20, Arup?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Are you talking about **Goruping** ? I think I didn't get you.. What do you mean by *mixing and matching* ?

Comment: Maybe so lets say top three: BIGGEST Big small. Instead of showing up in that order it would be like Big BIGGEST small. So in the first instance it would `.order("taggings_count DESC")` to figure out what's being limited and then from there it could be `.order('RANDOM()'))`

Comment: Okay :) I had tried `scope :top_20, -> {
   where("taggings_count != 0").order("taggings_count DESC").limit(4).order('RANDOM()')
 }` but then random only randomized within size order so if there were was BIGGEST #1 BIGGEST #2 Big #1 #2 it could randomize as BIGGEST #2 BIGGEST #1 Big #2 Big #1

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com sure.. let me think it.. I think possible.. but not sure yet.. The real problem is I need to think without data.. so.. takes time.. :/

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com What's the DB client you are using ?

Comment: Sq I think. I just added what my database looks like for this section in the question. Maybe I need to create a column `t.datetime "created_at"` for tag to create some variation between the sizes that way instead of using Random?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80304/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-anthonygalli-com).